# Issue using GridSpec and colorbar with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a specific plot using GridSpec. However with my code, colorbars are changing the width_ratios.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

data1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
x = np.linspace(1,10,10)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = GridSpec(2,2,figure=fig, width_ratios=[10,1])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
img = plt.imshow(data1, aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(location='left')

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
ax.plot(x, data1[0,:])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,:])
img = plt.imshow(data2, aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(location='right')

plt.show()
```

I would like the 1d plot to be more on the right and the second 2d plot to be extended on the left. (I don't want the colorbars to be both on left)

Comment: Try with add `fig.tight_layout()` after the line `gs = ...` and `fig.tight_layout()` at end of your codes

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly create axes for the colour bars to go in.  Hopefully this shows the idea (you might want to tweak the width ratios further).

See also https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/colorbar_placement.html

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

data1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
data2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
x = np.linspace(1,10,10)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = GridSpec(2, 4, figure=fig, width_ratios=[1, 10, 2, 1])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1])
img = plt.imshow(data1, aspect='auto')
cax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
plt.colorbar(cax=cax, location='left')

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,2:])
ax.plot(x, data1[0,:])

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0:3])
img = plt.imshow(data2, aspect='auto')
cax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,3])
plt.colorbar(cax=cax, location='right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: With your answer, there is one thing which is problematic. If you want the third column to be bigger, the colorbar will be also bigger. Not the same size as the left one.

Comment: Sure, but you could make four columns and have the line plot span the last two and the colour bar only span the last one.  As I said “you might want to tweak the number of columns and width ratios further”.

Comment: OK, now edited to show the line plot wider than the colorbars.